# How to find address of a variable?

Tags: vb.net

I know we can find it using & in C/C++ or some way in C#. What is the way in VB.NET?

Comment: In VB.NET you don't need the address of a variable. What are you trying to do?

Comment: the only way i could see this making sense if you were passing managed data to a native dll... in that case you would allocate the memory using Marshal...it would make more sense if you explained what you wanted to do...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this answer can indeed make the VB5/VB6 VarPtr function available in VB.Net.  Just fix the errors in the declaration.  I tried using it with memcpy to copy Integers and it worked.

Declare Function VarPtr Lib "MSVBVM60.DLL" Alias "VarPtr" (ByRef Variable As Integer) As Integer

Answer (score -1):

From [MicroSoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199824) i suggest a solution here:

Let `a` be an integer variable and `address` is a long variable which holds the address of `a`

```
 Declare Function adresMemory Lib "msvbvm50.dll" Alias "VarPtr" _
(ByVal Var As Integer) As Long
 Dim a As Integer = 10
 Dim address As Long = adresMemory(a)'<------ address holds the address of variable a
```

Comment: That page refers to VB6. The code you posted cannot work in any case, because you are passing `a` by value.